# How to implement a grid like Related Products in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have been trying to get this done for past many days. Not quite getting the logic. Here's what I am doing.

I want to create a **Magento 1.9.x** extension for **assigning videos to products**. I have completed the videos part. I am stuck on how to assign them to particular products. I want to show up grid in product edit page, just like Related, Upsell, Cross Sell products. This grid should be populated with the video information from my custom model.

I have researched a lot and I could find articles which explain how to assign other products to a particular product. I have also read articles on working of the **Grid Serializer**. But no article talks about assigning my **custom model** (table) entities with a particular product. I also tried to go through the logic of Related Products, but I am not quite understanding it.

I have done till here. I am showing up my videos in grid.

[image]

But I am not able to save them. Nor are they working when I try to edit an existing product. This is because I am not clear with the logic. Could someone share some light on this? Will appreciate any sort of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your grid serializer you have chosen the parameter name for the selected videos something like:

```
<action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>[[videos grid class]]</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedProducts</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>selected_videos</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>selected</reload_param_name>
                </action>
```

If not, just add it.
Now you should create an observer to associate the selected videos to the current product on save, you can add it on the event catalog_product_prepare_save in adminhtml.
the called method should do something like:

```
$selectedVideos = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('selected_videos', []);
$product->setData('custom_attribute_for_videos',
                    Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($selectedVideos)
                );
```

custom_attribute_for_videos is the code of the product attribute (of type array) that you are going to use in order to associate videos to products. otherwise,just if needed, you can create your joint table (products_videos) and save the relations there by setting the data (the video and the product ids) in the observer to the relation model and saving it.